# Extending sandbox timeout using laravel/homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm working on my first laravel project (using homestead), and now that I'm adding more records in the database, I get an nginx timeout after about a minute (but everything still loads in production, and when I pare back the data it loads in my sandbox).

How/where can I configure the timeout to be longer for my sandbox?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just SSH into Homestead and follow the instructions in [this article](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/increase-script-execution-time/). And just out of curiosity, what request takes more than a minute to execute?

Comment: thank you!  I did all three steps and did the reload commands, but it still gives a 504 nginx timeout at 60 seconds :(  I'll try again after work and if worse comes to worst I can use a smaller test data set.  As for what's taking so long, I'm not sure. I'm running this on my laptop (8GB of ram), not sure if that's enough.  All pages requiring a user login are having this issue (even very simple ones).  2 pages don't require a login: one  successfully loads in <3 seconds (a test gallery page that displays 800 images), and the other one times out  (has an auth login form and 450 images)

Comment: Loading 800 images at once onto a page is overkill. Instead, you should load a small portion of that and either use pagination, or some "infinite scrolling" plugin like [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/) which would allow you to load and append a small portion of the gallery as the user scrolls down (if that is something that would apply to your UI).

Comment: As for the slow page load, the RAM doesn't play any role unless you're loading huge amount of information on every page (and even then in most cases you'll get an out of memory error, because PHP is configured to use only a portion of the available memory). I suggest you read [this article](https://laravel-news.com/2015/02/laravel-debugbar/) about installing and working with Laravel Debugbar, because it can be really helpful in finding performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Wow- these look awesome- that infinite scrolling thing is exactly what I need in this case.  I can't thank you enough!